Sobolev inequality on exteriors of bounded open sets
Assume $1 \le p < n$ and let $p^*$ be the Sobolev conjugate of $p$, i.e. $p^* = np/(n - p)$. Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded open set. Let $u \in C^\infty(\Omega^c),\, \nabla u \in L^p(\Omega^c)$ with $u$ equal to $0$ in a neighborhood of $\Omega$. Is it true that $\|u \|_{L^{p^*}} \le C \|\nabla u\|_{L^p}$ for a constant $C$ that is independent of $\Omega$?

I am a bit confused. This is not true for any bounded $\Omega$. Just pick a function which is constant equal to $1$ far away from $\Omega$ and goes to zero near $\Omega$. Then $\nabla u$ is bounded with compact support, but $u$ is in no $L^p$. Is there an assumption missing?

The result is true since it holds on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and because $u$ has compact support.

@SeverinSchraven No assumptions missing hahaha. I was trying to prove something else and such an inequality would help me. The problem I was considering didn't allow for your counterexample, so I have blindly ignored it. Thanks!

@ToGle There is no assumption that $u$ has compact support (the assumption is that it vanishes in the neighborhood of a fixed bounded set).

@Cauchy'sSequence Maybe you can modify your question to reflect the property you really want.

@SeverinSchraven my bad I read a bit too fast... You are completely right.
